# Typescript Error on node_module that has higher React version

Tags: reactjs, typescript, node-modules

I have a `@company/module` that's made with React 18, but the main project is still using React 17. Right now, if I import this module, the tsc fails on the main project because of using its @types/react v17.0.44, which doesn't include the new types of React 18.

The error is: `Module "react" has no exported member 'useId'`

- Is there a way to fix this without upgrading the main project to React 18?
- How can I make the tsc to use the @types/react accordingly to the modules?

I have `skipLibCheck: true` and it still checks the module and fails.

This is the full tsconfig:

```
{
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "downLevelIteration": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this issue is to use a package like patch-package or resolutions in your package.json file to override the @types/react version used by your main project.

For example, you can add a resolutions field in your package.json like this:

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "^18.0.0"
}
```

This will force your main project to use version 18 of @types/react even if it was previously using version 17.

Alternatively, you can try to use a type-only import in your module's code to avoid importing the new types from React 18 that are causing the issue. For example, you can change the import statement to:

```
import type { UseIdHook } from 'react';
```

This will only import the type of the UseIdHook without actually importing the implementation, which should allow the code to compile without errors.

I hope this helps